# How to hover an edit text in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am stuck with an issue of hover on `edittext` when placed near the field.

**Required:**

When I place in `div1` or `div2` edittext field should be visible and it should be editable

When I place outside div1 or div2 edit text should not be visible only from and to should be visible.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="textboxes">
<ul>
    <li><input type="text" id="txt" /></li></ul>
</div>
<div class="edit">
<a href="#" id="edit"   runat="server" >edit</a>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.textboxes {margin:0; padding:0; display: none; }
.textboxes ul li {list-style-type:none; padding:5px 0 0;}
```

**jQuery:**

```
 $("#edit").click(function() {
      if ($('.textboxes').is(':visible')) {
         $('.textboxes').hide();
         // do save info
         //$(this).val('Edit');
     }
     else {
         $('.textboxes').show();
        // $(this).val('Edit');
     }



    $(this).hide().after('<span class="edit">' + $(this).val() + '</span>');  
});
```

Comment: why dont you just use 
.textboxes:hover {
your css here....
}

Comment: i have tried it but once edit text is visble after editing edit text is not hiding

Comment: "When i place in div1 or div2" place what..? "hover on `edittext`" where is `edittext` in shared html..? can you improve the question somehow so that its better understandable..?

Comment: Intially there would not be edit text thre will be from label and there will be a space at right side.when you hover over the from label edit text should be visible..how it can be achieved..can u able to get my point

Answer (score 1):

Check the below demo .. It might helps you..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UgBLt/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
        <div class="box">
            <div>From :</div>
            <div class="txt">India</div>
            <div class="input"><input type="text" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div>To :</div>
            <div class="txt">America</div>
            <div class="input"><input type="text" /></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
$(".box").mouseenter(function (e1) {
     var txt = $(this).children(".txt");
     input = $(this).children(".input");

    input.children("input").val(txt.html());
    txt.css("display", "none");
    input.css("display", "inline-block");

}).mouseleave(function (e2) {
    var txt = $(this).children(".txt");
    var input = $(this).children(".input");

    txt.html(input.children("input").val());
    input.css("display", "none");
    txt.css("display", "inline-block");
});
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Real nice example! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Mouse enter function in Jquery will help you( I hope so) to achieve  your requirement.

Here is an example

```
$('.textboxes').hide();

$( "#edit" )
  .mouseenter(function() {
    $('.textboxes').show();
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $('.textboxes').hide();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="showTextBox">
    <input type="text" id="textBox" style="visibility:hidden"></input>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("#showTextBox").mouseover(function() { 
    $("#textBox").css('visibility','visible'); 
});

$("#showTextBox").mouseout(function() { 
    $("#textBox").css('visibility','hidden');    
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/GWZ4N/3/)